# Create Variable with 4 Values in one line

Tags: powershell

I'm deploying NetworkDrives with powershell by reading a hash table like this:

```
$ITDrives = @{
    "l:" = "\\server\share";
    "m:" = "\\server\share";
    "o:" = "\\server\share";
    "p:" = "\\server\share";
    "v:" = "\\server\share";
}

[...]

$map.MapNetworkDrive($_.Name, $_.Value, $true)
```

[...] = there is some code in between.

Now i want to do the same for NetworkDrives which are in DMZ. Unfortunately, there are 4 Values I need there. "Letter, Path, Username and Passwor"

I can't create a Hashtable out of this. What other options do I have?

It should be something like this

```
    $DMZDrives = @(
    "u:" "\\SERVER1\SHARE" "domain\administrator" "$PW";
    "r:" "\\SERVER2\SHARE" "domain\administrator" "$PW";
    "w:" "\\SERVER3\SHARE" "domain\administrator" "$PW";
    )
```

Comment: yes, i also thought of that. But I don't like to use any csv, xml or anything. I'd rather put it in the head-part of my code if that's possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to work with `PsCustomObject`:

```
$DMZDrives = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Letter='u:'; Path='\\SERVER1\SHARE'; Username='domain\administrator'; Password='yourPassword'}    
    [PSCustomObject]@{Letter='r:'; Path='\\SERVER2\SHARE'; Username='domain\administrator'; Password='yourPassword'}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Letter='w:'; Path='\\SERVER3\SHARE'; Username='domain\administrator'; Password='yourPassword'}
)
```

Output of `$DMZDrives`:

```
Letter Path            Username             Password    
------ ----            --------             --------    
u:     \\SERVER1\SHARE domain\administrator yourPassword
r:     \\SERVER2\SHARE domain\administrator yourPassword
w:     \\SERVER3\SHARE domain\administrator yourPassword
```

Now you have a list of your desired objects and can use well known filters, for example:

```
$DMZDrives | where Letter -eq 'u:'
```

Or loop over them and map the network drives:

```
$DMZDrives | % {
    $map.MapNetworkDrive($_.Letter, $_.Path, $true, $_.Username, $_.Password)
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, an array of custom objects is what you get if you do import-csv and put the result in a variable with no type specified.